# Transfer Data between two android phones using Usb host Api

Tags: android, usb, host

I am trying to send some data from one Android phone(Nexus 5), which is working as Usb Host, to Android tablet(Samsung Tab 4).

I am using bulkTransfer() method to transfer data from Nexus 5, which is returning the length of data that has been transferred successfully.

My question is **How can I verify on the other end (at Samsung Tab), that yes I am getting the data that I had transferred from Nexus 5 ?**

Here is some code snippet of transferring data

```
   usbDeviceConnection = manager.openDevice(device);
   boolean flag =  usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);
   String text = textValue.getText().toString();
   byteArray = text.getBytes();

   //  data transfer
   int a = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut, byteArray, byteArray.length, 0);

   if(a>0){
              textInfo.setText("Data has been transferred successfully..."
                             +"\n"+"Length of data: "+a
   );
```

Please help me to do this task...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After digging the **Usb Host API** I have found something that the other end (Samsung Tab) can work in **Accessory mode** and we can access the **Usb Host**(Nexus 5) by using the **"android.hardware.usb.accessory"** library.

Since the android phone who can support the **Usb Host** feature for example like **Nexus 5** can access the device connected to it using **"android.hardware.usb.host"** library.

The other one for example **Samsung Tab(It must support [AOAP Protocol](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol.html)  )** who does not support the **Usb Host** feature will access the device connected to it using **"android.hardware.usb.accessory"** library.

To understand The Usb Host feature you can open the link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

To understand The Usb Accessory feature you can open the link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html